# How can I send notification from Postman using FCM?

Tags: flutter, dart, postman

I am using a Post method from the postman to send notifications to my flutter app, If I include the body outside of the notification in this way I can send notifications.

```
{
    "to": "cu6HFvgXSCyKz5kjp..........",
    "notification": {
        "sound": "default",
        "body": "test body",
        "title": "test title",
        "content_available": true,
        "priority": "high"
    },
    "data": {
        "sound": "default",
        "body": "test body",
        "title": "test title",
        "content_available": true,
        "priority": "high",
        "ride_request_id":"asdfasd"
    }
}
```

I can parse the data to get my value from `ride_request_id` but the catch is I get double notification, so FCM has suggested including the body inside the notification, Now, neither do I get the notification nor able to parse it. Although in Postman it shows as successful.

```
{
    "to": "cu6HFvgXSCyKz5kjp..........",
    "notification": {
        "sound": "default",
        "body": "test body",
        "title": "test title",
        "content_available": true,
        "priority": "high",
        "data": {
            "sound": "default",
            "body": "test body",
            "title": "test title",
            "content_available": true,
            "priority": "high",
            "ride_request_id": "asdfasd"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an article about sending a notification using postman:

[Test FCM Notification with POSTMAN](https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3)

Comment: Thank you but the article is outdated.